# C++ Template: typenames and ||s in the angle brackets

Tags: c++, templates

I'm browsing this piece of code right here, the TensorRT Engine serialization and deserialization source code. I stumbled across some syntax I've never seen before.

```
struct Serializer<T, // ??
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value || std::is_enum<T>::value || std::is_pod<T>::value>::type>
{ // ...
```

What is the code after the commented question marks doing? There is no narrower question, this syntax is completely foreign to me. I'd be greatly appreciative of any resources I can read to learn more about what this is doing exactly.

I usually present a list of google queries I've performed before asking questions, but I'm not even sure what to call this pattern.

Source Code: https://github.com/NVIDIA/TensorRT/blob/492878b2df3c9bf19a26c2b66cba129f450475bc/plugin/common/serialize.hpp#L45

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae

Comment: Never in a million years would I have thought "Ah, SFINAE is probably the name of this." I appreciate the link, thank you very much.

Comment: @npengra317 before you get down the SFINAE rabbit hole, you should be aware that since C++20, there are [concepts and constraints](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) which achieve the same thing but with much less insanity

Comment: This is an incredibly useful resource, and provides a lot of insight on why one would want this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax evaluates to `void` (to match the presumable default template argument) or fails to do so. You may need to review [C++ templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters) again.
[SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) is a technique used to constrain [template specializations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization) via that failure. Since C++20 [concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) provide a much better mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for compiling the comments into an answer for future users. Enjoy the accepted answer sir.